# Disable CSRF only for dev env in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, yaml

In a SF2 classic application, how can i disable the form login CSRF only for dev environment ?

config.yml :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: en_US }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: "%kernel.debug%"
    form:            true
    csrf_protection: true
```

security.yml :

```
firewalls:
    dev:

    pattern:                        ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security:                       false

login:
    pattern:                        ^/user/(login|reset-request|send-email|check-email)$
    provider:                       chain_provider
    anonymous:                      true

main:
    pattern:                        ^/
    provider:                       chain_provider
    form_login:
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        check_path:                 my_security_check
        login_path:                 my_security_login
    logout:
        path:                       my_security_logout
    remember_me:
        key:                        %secret%
        name:                       MYKEY
        lifetime:                   3600
    anonymous:                      false
```

security_dev.yml :

```
firewalls:
main:
    form_login:
        check_path:                 my_security_check
        login_path:                 my_security_login
```

The purpose is to unset the `csrf_provider` by overriding the security configuration with the inclusion of `security_test` :

config_dev.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: security_dev.yml }
```

I can't set the `csrf_provider` to null or false because SF2 will not accept these values.
But with this inclusion, the key is always present.

So the question could be more general : how can i completely override a configuration array with another yaml inclusion ?

Thanks by advance,

JM

Answer (score 4):

It makes me wonder why would you want to disable CSRF for development, but if you're sure you want to do that, it's actually pretty simple to do. Just override the setting in `config_dev.yml`:

```
framework:
    # ...
    csrf_protection: false
```

Comment: My real need is to disable CSRF for my test environment because some of my behat features fail because of CSRF when the test machine is overloaded and i wanted to be more simple in my question ;). Your solution is for disabling CSRF for the whole application, not for the sole login form, but i will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Your question was *In a SF2 classic application, how can I disable the form login CSRF only for dev environment?* Nothing regarding the login form there. ;)

Comment: Maybe the title is not clear enough. I want to "unset" the configuration key `crsf_provider` of the login form in the `firewalls` section